# How to assign col only on desktop in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Bootstrap 5 allow to use .col class display equal-width columns but I can't find a way to use it only on desktop and assign a 6 column on mobile

I try with this but it doesn't work

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg">
      Column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version (specifically) are you using? Also note there is no col-xs-* in Bootstrap 5

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 5.0

Comment: That's not a specific version... Which specific version? 5.0.1, 5.0.2, 5.1.0, etc?

Comment: Bootstrap v5.0.2

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<div class="col-6 col-sm">
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work it always display 2 elements per row

Comment: if you want 6 elements per row, you need to use col-2 instead of col-6

Comment: It is a BUG in 5.0.2, they marked as already answered "Bootstrap v5 Grid is not working in "col-lg" case"